# PHP move_uploaded_file filesystems

Tags: php, mysql, file-upload, upload, filesystems

everyone.  i am having trouble getting PHP to move files up into a directory.  mkdir works just fine in creating the directory and the mysql table is getting all files inserted.  the move_uploaded_file step is not working right, though.

```
        //filestorage variables 
        $uniqid = uniqid();
        $folder = 'documents/' . $uniqid; //drill down further with m/d currentDate
        $file   = $_FILES['file'];
        $i      = 0;

        //iterate through $_FILES array
        foreach ($file as $f){      
            $temp   = $file['tmp_name'][$i];
            $name   = $file['name'][$i];
            $dest   = $folder . '/' . $name;

        //store file on server      
            if(!file_exists($folder)){
                mkdir($folder);
                chmod($folder, 0755);
                }
            if(isset($_FILES['file'])){                     
                move_uploaded_file($temp, $dest);
                echo "upload complete"; 
                if(move_uploaded_file($temp, $dest)){
                    echo '<p> successful step </p>' . $dest;
                   }
               }

        //prepare and submit files to database  
            if (count($_FILES) > 0){
                if(is_uploaded_file($temp)) {
                    echo '<p>' . "The file is, in fact, uploaded." . '</p>';
                    $sql = "INSERT INTO uploads (`file_dest`) VALUES ( :dest )";
                    $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
                    $stmt->bindParam(':dest', $dest, PDO::PARAM_STR, strlen($dest));
                    $stmt->execute();
                    echo 'the following file was uploaded <p><img src="' . $dest . '" /></p>';
                    echo 'from ' . $folder . '/' . $name;
                    }
                }
            $i++;
            }
```

do i need to fully qualify the destination name down to root level?  i broke something at a certain point after making the directory names a bit trickier.  this was working when the folder was just called "documents" (of course, the code was a little different then, too.

the error message that I am receiving in apache's error log are as follows:

[Thu Jun 19 11:30:01 2014] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Warning:  chmod() [function.chmod]: Operation not permitted in /Volumes/Secure/project/Web/Webroot/public_html/index.php on line 65, referer: MyWebpage

[Thu Jun 19 11:30:01 2014] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Warning:  move_uploaded_file(documents/53a310094d082/0000b.jpg) [function.move-uploaded-file]: failed to open stream: Permission denied in /Volumes/Secure/project/Web/Webroot/public_html/index.php on line 68, referer: MyWebpage

[Thu Jun 19 11:30:01 2014] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Warning:  move_uploaded_file() [function.move-uploaded-file]: Unable to move '/private/var/tmp/phptrm0HP' to 'documents/53a310094d082/0000b.jpg' in /Volumes/Secure/
project/Web/Webroot/public_html/index.php on line 68, referer: MyWebpage

Comment: Your code is dangerous. You're directly using `['name']` in your destination path, which allows a malicious user to scribble files of their choosing ANYWHERE on your server.

Comment: You have a missing closing brace `}` for `if(isset($_FILES['file'])){` and for `if(isset($_FILES['file'])){`

Comment: Add `$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);` right after the connection is opened.

Comment: Thanks for these recommendations.  Any input on the permissions problem I'm asking about?

Answer (score 0):

The issue came from using an external volume on Mac OSX.  It automatically marks this option on the volume:

Ignore ownership permissions

After un-checking the option, mkdir and similar commands work fine from the web server.